# How to find a function from an array

Tags: functions

I have an 2 dimensional array like the following.

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|     | 10   | 14   | 18   | 22   | 26   | 30   | 34   | 38   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1   | 660  | 924  | 1188 | 1122 | 1326 | 1530 | 1666 | 1862 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 51  | 960  | 1344 | 1728 | 1474 | 1742 | 2010 | 2278 | 2546 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 101 | 1060 | 1484 | 1908 | 1584 | 1872 | 2160 | 2414 | 2698 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 151 | 1140 | 1596 | 2052 | 1694 | 2002 | 2310 | 2550 | 2850 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 201 | 1230 | 1722 | 2214 | 1826 | 2158 | 2490 | 2686 | 3002 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 251 | 1320 | 1848 | 2376 | 1936 | 2288 | 2640 | 2822 | 3154 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 301 | 1400 | 1960 | 2520 | 2046 | 2418 | 2790 | 3026 | 3382 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 351 | 1470 | 2058 | 2646 | 2156 | 2548 | 2940 | 3298 | 3686 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 401 | 1480 | 2072 | 2664 | 2222 | 2626 | 3030 | 3434 | 3838 |
+-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

The first line at the top and the first column at the left are variables used to calculate the value inside this array (respectively x and y).
For example, if x = 22 and y = 51, the corresponding value is 1474.

I want to find a function/a formula that would allow me to calculate, given x and y the value corresponding to this array.

---

My problem is that I don't really know how to proceed to find this function. Is it possible ? If so, could you explain how I could do to find this function ?

Comment: Do you want a continuous function that does this?

Comment: is there a context for the data?

Comment: You might want to look up two dimensional Lagrange interpolation.

Comment: @cheesyfluff yes a continuous function would be great, but what i really want is the method used to find such function.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I don't think any context is relevant here. I want to know how to obtain a function from an array of value.

Comment: you might manage an asymptotic function, but the data looks too random for an actual function

Comment: If the context is not relevant, then your array **is** your function; it can be continued in any way or not continued at all, these answers would all be equally valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow discontinuous functions, there are infinitely many such functions that satisfy these requirements. This similar to asking to find a function $f(x,y)$ that satisfies $f(0,0)=0$. Without any context, a function
$$f(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{matrix}
660&x=10,y=1\\
960&x=10,y=51\\
1060& x=10,y=101\\
\vdots&\\
\end{matrix}
\right.$$
that simply maps the values in the array to the desired points would do.

However, I noticed that all of the values in the table are multiples of $x$. Dividing the table by $x$ then gives the coefficient array
$$\begin{matrix}
\\
\hline
1\\
51\\
101\\
151\\
201\\
251\\
301\\
351\\
401\\
\end{matrix}\left|
\begin{matrix}
10&14&18&22&26&30&34&38\\
\hline
66&66&66&51&51&51&49&49\\
96&96&96&67&67&67&67&67\\
106&106&106&72&72&72&71&71\\
114&114&114&77&77&77&75&75\\
123&123&123&83&83&83&79&79\\
132&132&132&88&88&88&83&83\\
140&140&140&93&93&93&89&89\\
147&147&147&98&98&98&97&97\\
148&148&148&101&101&101&101&101\\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Interpret this however you want.

Comment: Whoops, I rotated the two variables because I'm used to having $x$ pointing to the right of the positive $y$ direction. Fixed.